# Building an API in Express.js, Getting "Cannot GET /api"

Tags: javascript, api, express

Getting Cannot GET /api when I put in my query, I go to localhost:3000 and get what I expect returned which is "Random User API" but when I put in my query 
http://localhost:3000/api?results=100. I get the Cant GET/api. Can't figure out where it's coming from

index.js

```
let express = require('express'),
route = require('./routes/routes.js');

let app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', route.index);
app.get('/app', route.api);

app.listen(3000);
```

routes.js

```
var myNames = require("../names.json");

var MAX_RESULTS = 1000;

exports.index = function(req, res) {
  res.send("Random User API");
};

exports.api = function(req, res) {
  this.results = req.query.results;
  this.seed = req.query.seed;
  res.send(generateNames(this.results, this.seed));
};

function generateNames(results, seed) {
  this.results = results;
  if (this.results > MAX_RESULTS) {
    this.results = MAX_RESULTS;
  }
  this.seed = seed;

  var rand = require("random-seed").create(this.seed);
  var gender;
  var picRand;
  var picNum;
  var genRand;
  var firstname, lastname, address, city, state, postcode;
  var username;
  var phone;

  var names = {
    results: []
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < this.results; i++) {
    genRand - rand(2);
    picRand = rand(150) + 1;

    if (picRand < 10) {
      picNum = "00" + picRand;
    } else if (picRand < 100) {
      picNum = "0" + picRand;
    } else {
      picNum = "" + picRand;
    }

    if (genRand == 0) {
      gender = "male";
      picLarge = "http://localhost:3000/images/m" + picNum + ".jpg";
      firstname = myNames.male_names[rand(myNames.male_names.length)];
    } else {
      gender = "female";
      picLarge = "http://localhost:3000/images/f" + picNum + ".jpg";
      firstname = myNames.female_names[rand(myNames.female_names.length)];
    }

    lastname = myNames.last_names[rand(myNames.last_name.length)];

    address =
      myNames.last_names[rand(myNames.last_names.length)] +
      " " +
      myNames.street_types[rand(myNames.street_types.length)];

    postcode = rand(90000) + 10000;
    phone = rand(999) + 120 + "-" + rand(999) + 100 + "-" + rand(9999) + 1000;

    var person = {
      gender: gender,
      name: {
        first: firstname,
        last: lastname
      },
      location: {
        street: address,
        city: city,
        state: state,
        postcode: postcode
      },
      email: email,
      login: {
        username: username,
        password: password
      },
      dob: {
        date: date,
        age: age
      },
      phone: phone,
      cell: cell,
      picture: {
        large: picLarge,
        medium: picMedium,
        thumbnail: thumbnail
      }
    };
    names.results.push(person);
  }
  return names;
}
```

I'm expecting my data to be displayed in a JSON format

Answer (score 2):

you are using /app instead of /api

```
app.get('/app', route.api);
```

Comment: Thank youuu, can't believe I missed that haha